# Вторая встреча сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Санкт-Петербурге

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

Stack Overflow – это в первую очередь сообщество, сообщество неравнодушных коллег, которые каждый день помогают друг другу знаниями. На мой взгляд, встречи в реальной жизни могут привнести недостающей социальной составляющей.

С предвкушением спешу анонсировать *встречу участников сообщества Stack Overflow на русском в Санкт-Петербурге*! Это уже вторая по счету встреча в Санкт–Петербурге и четвертая встреча сообщества в общем.

Встреча не состоится без вашего участия! Если вы планируете посетить мероприятие, пожалуйста, заполните [специальную форму](https://goo.gl/i9Iffs).

Мы планируем встретиться чуть менее чем через две недели, 6-го или 7-го октября. Место встречи и тематика определится по результатам опроса. После определения даты, места, времени и тематики, я отпишусь всем участникам по почте, указанной в учётной записи на Stack Overflow на русском.

С нетерпением ждем ваших откликов!

Comment: Вижу несогласованное использование `Вы-вы` :)

Comment: уууу, я тоже футболку хочу :-)

Comment: Жаль, хотелось бы и у нас в городе.

Comment: @Other Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком именно городе?

Comment: Воронеж. [][][][]

Comment: От лица всех, живущих не в Петербурге: трансляция будет?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Предполагаю, что будет формат посиделок. Как таковой трансляции не будет, но обязательно будет Hangouts, как в прошлый раз!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky с последующим hangover

Comment: Будут ли выдавать значки ["Я не робот"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335432)?

Comment: @РоманХимов, а что делать если я робот и хочу значок подтверждающий это?

Comment: @Утка: ха! это же специальный значок, само введение которого должно заставить роботов страдать и мучаться в своей неполноценности. Наконец-то люди смогут задоминировать роботов на Стеке!

Comment: печалька что не в выходные, я бы из мск приехал(

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov В прошлом году предлагалось выбирать между пт и сб. За субботу было крайне мало голосов, к сожалению.

Comment: да выходные было бы интересней

Comment: да, в выходные можно было бы рассмотреть предложение, а так работа..

Comment: @Утка: боюсь, про доминирование я погорячился, сейчас ситуация ровно обратная --- теперь уже [робот получил значок "Не робот"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335736/). Опасное время.

Comment: И что в итоге, была встреча или ещё будет?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, была! Было 11 человек. Все здорово, только чуть–чуть шумно было :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а есть где отзывы почитать или мнения?)