# Выпуск №2 с @Nofate и @etki 07.06.2017 в 11:32. Присоединяйтесь!

Tags: обсуждение, видеочат

**UPD:** Интерактивчик. На два вопроса с собеседований, которые были упомянуты в трансляции, объявляется конкурс. Два участника, озвучившие первыми правильный ответ получат фирменные призы (по одному победителю на вопрос). Вопросы - в ответах ниже, отвечайте в комментариях.

---

С радостью спешу пригласить всех участников сообщества присоединиться к видеочату 07.06.2017 в 11:32 (утра) по московскому времени. Гостями второго выпуска будут хорошо всем известные:

- [@Nofate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1984/nofate), неоднократно избранный модератор сообщества Stack Overflow на русском, знаток языка [Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers);
- [@etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki), звукорежиссер по образованию, программист по призванию, один из лучших участников по метке [PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers), а также в списке лучших по [Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers).

Видео будет доступно в реальном времени на канале сообщества: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsJwpzQEcuM.

#### Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы гостям!

Главная цель видеочата – узнать друг друга поближе. Расскажите, гостям о том, что вам интересно в них! Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы участникам выпуска!

Во время выпуска, ваши вопросы участникам выпуска вы можете задать, например, в [чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Обязательно, задавая вопрос, упомяните `@NicolasChabanovsky` и/или имя участника, кому вопрос адресован , чтобы я (мы) мог своевременно отреагировать на ваш вопрос. Также вы можете отправить ваш вопрос к участникам заранее мне на почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com).

Присоединяйтесь!

Comment: Время, я требую время! С секундами!

Comment: О, сидел вместе с этими ребятами ... [за одним столом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3792/176217) :)

Comment: @alexolut, с обоями?

Comment: @Grundy с плиткой и сайдингом!

Comment: Тайм-менеджмент, имхо, надо корректировать. Прошлый раз ещё понятно, с Сибирью согласовывали ... а тут самый разгар рабдня.

Comment: @alexolut, питерцы же, эти бездельники вообще не работают!

Comment: @Grundy да ваще лентяи ... ой ... подождите ... я же ...

Comment: @alexolut, а есть пожелания по времени трансляций?

Comment: @Nofate я думаю, такое надо в нерабочее время устраивать. Либо вечерами, либо на выходных.

Comment: @alexolut активность в чате обычно высокая именно в рабочее время ) А вечером все на диване сериальчики смотрят. (Хотя мне бы тоже было удобнее выступить в выходные или после работы)

Comment: Но вообще, я уверен, это обсуждаемо (для последующих выпусков). Можем голосовалку запилить.

Comment: @Nofate одно дело, от случая к случаю заглядывать в чат, другое дело на час+ подряд залипнуть в видеочате.

Comment: А где Выпуск №1?

Comment: @Alex78191 тут: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5136

Comment: А из каких соображений было выбрано время (рабочее время, рабочий день)? Поучаствовал бы, но в это время неудобно.

Comment: @post_zeew так кости легли

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Весьма странный способ.

Comment: @post_zeew время выбиралось исходя из пожеланий приглашенных участников. На сколько я могу судить, наиболее оптимальное время 6 или 7 вечера буднего дня (в выходные у многих есть семейные дела).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Вы сейчас о каких участниках? Ибо [вот](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5387/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-2-%d1%81-nofate-%d0%b8-etki-07-06-2017-%d0%b2-1132-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c#comment20120_5387).

Comment: @alexolut, я о гостях данного выпуска.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky так а я о ком ссылку привел? :)

Comment: @alexolut прав )

Comment: @alexolut на выходных практически никого нет, ни среди гостей, ни среди слушателей (зрителей).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я уже говорил , что есть большая разница (по крайней мере, для меня) в том чтобы в течения дня несколько раз заходить по 5 минут и в том, чтобы провести час+ на сайте непрерывно. Более того, если сделать анонс с датой и временем заблаговременно, реально заинтересованных людей собрать будет проще. Вы же, надеюсь, не будете так же утверждать, что и очередную встречу ruSO в баре надо делать в середине рабочего дня?!

Comment: Поддерживаю @alexolut. Среди рабочего дня и на своем рабочем месте посидеть час за просмотром ютуба не получится.

Answer (score 2):

Озвученная задачка:

Требуется описать архитектуру сервиса, управляющего состоянием телефонных линий (или других ресурсов). Требования к сервису - API подразумевает захват/освобождение конкретной линии и захват случайной линии из пула доступных; вся инфраструктура, поддерживающая сервис, может в любой момент потерять связь с любым узлом (HA). Требуется в общих чертах описать архитектуру, самописную или с использованием сторонних инструментов, которая позволит реализовать удовлетворяющий условиям сервис.

Задачка специально размытая, на нее есть как минимум несколько ответов, из известных мне нет ни одного идеального.

Comment: Зайти на телефонную станцию и посмотреть как там? Работают же, не жалуются. Всё идеально.

Comment: какого рода Вы ожидаете ответ? структура бд, используемые решения на стороне сервера?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60054/discussion-on-answer-by-etki--2--nofate--etki-07-06-2017--1132-).

Comment: @Sergey станция такого функционала не предоставляет

Comment: @Bald с помощью чего будет достигнуто условие высокой доступности и позволит сервису сохранить хотя бы частичный функционал в случае потери связи с любым из узлов

Comment: Ethernet сеть на одной шине работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вторая задачка.

Пятеро хипстеров отложили свои макбуки и решили выявить три самых быстрых гироскутера, чтобы записать про них обзор на Vimeo. Для этого они отобрали 25 интересных моделей и устраивают заезды из Старбакса до ближайшей фалафельной.

За какое минимальное число заездов они *гарантированно* решат свою задачу, если айфоны уже разрядились, и секундомером воспользоваться не получится?

Comment: Просьба не жульничать и не гуглить )

Comment: 5 "пробных" заездов. Один "заезд победителей" (узнаём первого). Далее один заезд между вторым из "заезда победителей" и вторыми из "пробных" (узнаём второго и, возможно, третьего). Далее (возможно) ещё один заезд, где победитель прошлого заменён на стоящего за ним из пробного заезда. **Итого 8.** Хотя у меня острое ощущение, что я что-то пропустил, что не изменит ответ, но изменит способ выбора гироскутеров для восьмого.

Comment: @D-side а как же непредвиденные обстоятельства? У чего-то что-то сбойнуло, скоротнуло, или дорожка неровная? нужно как минимум несколько тестов на одну группу участников. А то если на одной дорожке дерево, то гарантирован проигрыш даже самому быстрому)

Comment: А-а. Проще даже. Повторяем "заезд победителей", заменяя на каждом шаге прошлого победителя на стоящего за ним в пробных заездах. Ответ всё ещё 8.

Comment: В "заезде победителей" нет смыла гонять последние 2 места по 2му кругу. Итого: 7й (и последний) заезд: 2 и 3е место из заезда победителей 2 и 3е места из первого заезда победившего скутера и 2е место из 2го места. 8й заезд не нужен. **итого - 7 заездов**

Comment: @Crantisz да, верно. И меньше уже невозможно, т. к. 6 не сделает достаточного числа сравнений. Поздравляю! :)

Comment: @D-side а почему? если мы сразу победителя из каждой пятерки выявляем, плюя на погрешности, то почему в 6-ом заезде сразу и не определить все три места?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский представьте ситуацию, в которой два или три самых быстрых скутера попали в один пробный заезд..

Comment: @D-side как я описал выше - есть различные обстоятельства, которые так и так могут не дать самым быстрым приехать первыми) Но ладно. Спишем на моё занудство)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский при возникновении вышеописанных обстоятельств считаем заезд несостоявшимся по техническим причинам, всего-то.